# plotting against datetime when there are two indices, pandas, python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have the dataframe shown below,

```
                USD 
state    date
  AL     01/01    10
         01/08    15
           .
           .
           .
         12/30    8

  AK     01/01    10
         01/08    15
           .
           .
           .
         12/30    8
```

for every state.
I want to plot date vs USD for every state in one graph.
How can I do this?

Comment: `df.unstack().plot()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `unstack` and `plot`

```
df.unstack(0).plot()
```

Data input

```
df
Out[92]: 
             USD
state date      
AL    01/01   10
      01/08   15
      12/30    8
AK    01/01    3
      01/08    5
      12/30    2
```

[image]

Comment: I was missing the `0`. You got it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aha happy new year :-)

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks yall!

Comment: @HirotakaNakagame if this is what you need can you consider upvote and accept ?:-)